# Compare variance of 2 groups with repeated measures

Tags: r, variance, repeated-measures

Lets say participants are assigned to either an easy group or a hard group. They perform multiple trials of a computer task and reaction time (RT) is measured for each trial. The data looks something like this:

```
id trial group RT
1  1     easy  234
1  2     easy  542
1  3     easy  231
2  1     hard  112
2  2     hard  135
2  3     hard  435
...
```

How would I test the hypothesis that the hard group has a larger variability in reaction time than the easy group?

One way to do this might be to calculate the mean RT for each participant and use something like Levene's test to compare the variance of the easy and hard groups.  I would like to avoid this as it's throwing away information needlessly

Without collapsing across the trials we would run into issues with independence as multiple rows of data come from the same participant. I've typically used multilevel models to get around this, with something like this in R:

```
lmer(RT ~ group + (1 + group | id), data=df)
```

That model will test for a difference between group *means*, but is there a way to use a multilevel model like to test for a difference between group *variances*? If not, whats the appropriate way to test for variance differences when multiple measurements per participant are involved?

Comment: You could use `nlme` and specify a constant variance function for each group. Something like this: `lme(RT~group, random = ~1|id, weights=varIdent(form=~1|group))`. Then perform a likelihood ratio test against a model that doesn't allow the groups to have separate variances.

Comment: so basically that will allow each group to have a different variance, and the test between that model and the base model (without weights) will tell us if the variances of easy and hard are significantly different? is this possible with `lme4`?

Comment: At least that's my intuition about a possible test, yes. I would be interested in what others on this site have to say. Unfortunately, this is not currently possible in `lme4`, as far as I know.